# Confusing matrix generation example in Lua

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, lua

If you want to create NxM matrix in Lua you basically do the following:

```
function get_zero_matrix(rows, cols)
  matrix = {}
  for i=1, rows do
    matrix[i] = {}
    for j=1, cols do
      matrix[i][j] = 0
    end
  end
  return matrix
end
```

However, on the official Lua website I've seen the [second variant](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.2.html):

```
function get_zero_matrix2(rows, cols)
  mt = {}
  for i=1, rows do
    for j=1, cols do
      mt[i*cols + j] = 0
    end
  end
  return mt
end
```

First, I don't understand how it works. How `[i*M + j]` index is supposed to create rows and columns? 
Second, I tried this variant, it works but what it returns is actually an array, not NxM matrix:

```
M = function get_zero_matrix2(10, 20)
print(#M, #M[1])

> attempt to get length of a nil value (field '?')
```

Can you please explain how the second variant works?
Maybe I am misinterpreting it.

Comment: Better make `matrix` a local variable...

Comment: The second variant is merely a flattened 1d array that mimics a 2d matrix, thus M[1] is a number instead of a row/col of a matrix, and #M[1] is invalid. This should help the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand how it works.

For a 2D array of dimension `N` (rows) x `M` (cols), the total number of required elements = `N * M`. Now creating `N * M` elements in one shot as a single array, we will essentially have a 1D array (flattened 2D array) in memory. Since the formula assumes array index start as `0` and not `1` (the usual Lua's convention), we'll follow `0`: the first `M` items with indices `[0, M - 1]` form row `0`, next `M` items with indices `[M, 2M - 1]` form row `1`, and so on.

Memory layout for a `5 x 2` array; index `4` in this 1D array is `(2, 0)` in the 2D array.

```
   --+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--
 ... | 0,0 | 0,1 | 1,0 | 1,1 | 2,0 | 2,1 | 3,0 | 3,1 | 4,0 | 4,1 | ...
   --+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--

     |-- row 0 --|-- row 1 --|-- row 2 --|-- row 3 --|-- row 4 --|
```

To access element `(i, j)`, one would get past `i - 1` rows and then access the `j`<sup>th</sup> item on the `i`<sup>th</sup> row. But the index is already one lesser, since the index starts at `0`, so `i` can be used as-is. Thus `i * rows + j` gives the right index.

> How `[i*M + j]` index is supposed to create rows and columns?

It doesn't. It's an abstraction over a 1D array of numbers, giving the interface of a matrix. In languages like C, declaring a 2D array, most implementations do something similar. `int a[2][3]` would create an array of 6 integers and do the indexing with the formula above, so this is not an uncommon pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The variant available on *Lua PiL* is actually representation/mapping of a 2D array as a 1D array.

Basically, consider the following 2x3 array/matrix:

```
{
    {11, 12, 13},
    {21, 22, 23}
}
```

The variant, instead creates it as:

```
{
    [4] = 11,
    [5] = 12,
    .
    .
    .
    [9] = 23
}
```

Now, when you want to, let's say, get `matrix[1][x]`, you'll instead fetch:

```
matrix[1 * rows + x]
```

It **does not**, in any way create rows and columns. It is just data stored in a single row of numbers. You will have to implement your own logic; which here, essentially; is `i * M + j`.

---

The `i*M + j` is usually seen in languages with 0-indexing array, like C, where the matrix would be:

```
{
    [0] = 11,
    [1] = 12,
    [2] = 13,
    .
    .
    .
    [5] = 23
}
```